# Trouble sanitizing HTML in angular 6/ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I would like to sanitize the HTML tags out of text coming in from the server on my ionic/angular 6 app.  The object looks like this

```
{note: '<p>lorem ipsum</p>'}
```

The error I'm currently getting is `urlSan is not defined`, but on top of that, I am not super sure I am using this feature correctly. I used a [version of this walkthrough](http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20180323-AngularDomSanitizationInIonic.html)

This is the `page.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingService } from '../loading.service';
import { FinaeoApiService } from '../finaeo-api.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-individual',
  templateUrl: './contact-individual.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-individual.page.scss'],
})
export class ContactIndividualPage implements OnInit {
  contact: any;
  initials: string = '';
  safeHTML:  SafeResourceUrl;

  private htmlValue: string;

  constructor(
    private loadingService: LoadingService,
    private api: FinaeoApiService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {   }

  urlSan(value: string) {
    this.htmlValue = value;
    this.safeHTML = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
  };

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.loadingService.load(async () => {
      const routeParams = <any> this.route.params;
      this.contact = await this.api.getModel('Contact', routeParams._value.id);
      _.forEach(this.contact.notes, function(html) {
        urlSan(html.note)
      })
      this.initials = this.contact.firstName != null ? this.contact.firstName.charAt(0) + this.contact.lastName.charAt(0) : '';
    });
  }


}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `this.urlSan`?

Comment: why your not using bypassSecurityTrustHtml insted of bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl that your using? you said you want HTML not url...
Also you need to use this.urlSan()